# Basic requirement to Run ASP.Net 2.0 Application in IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am very new in IIS 7.0 (Using in Windows Server 2008).
I have my Web application developed in VS 2005 or ASP.Net 2.0. in Windows Server 2003 system.

Now i am migrating to Windows server 2008 + IIS 7.0, So please can any tell me what are the basic setting i have to perform on IIS 7.0 to run my existing application without any changes in code.

I read somewhere that i have to change my Web.config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont worry my friend, i just follow the following simple steps and it works for me

1- i copy the folder containing the application into the www root folder

2- open IIS from RUN INETMGR and check the application pool: make sure it contains .NET 2

[image]

3-convert to application

[image]

4-choose the classic .NET v2

[image]

5- set permissions and run the application

Good Luck !

Comment: Mow I am able to run and login in my application from VS.But when i run same application from IIS it will giving me error while login. I thing it is because ASPNET user not exist. What i have to do now?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very useful link

[ASP.NET 2.0 Breaking Changes on IIS 7.0](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/381/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis-70/)

if you face any trouble, send your problem as comment and i will answer it

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change your application to classic mode instead of Integrated mode, there are some gotchas moving into integrated mode. Its something to consider at least. Hopefully you have the opportunity to test before going live with IIS 7.